# jxcore crashed at JX_CreateEmptyObject in sub instance creation thread

Tags: jxcore

I am currently working on embedding jxcore to my robotic system program.When i am testing embedding  api ,i produced the following code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ScriptEngine.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include "thread"
#include "mutex"


int main(int argc, char **args) {


    char* homeFolder = args[0];


    JX_InitializeOnce(homeFolder);
    JX_InitializeNewEngine();

    JX_DefineMainFile("console.log('parent engine')");

    JXValue obj;

    // Parent engine created at main thread ,and JX_CreateEmptyObject worked ok!
    JX_CreateEmptyObject(&obj); 
    JXValue global;
    JX_GetGlobalObject(&global);
    JX_SetNamedProperty(&global, "NativeBridge", &obj);
    JX_Free(&obj);
    JX_Free(&global);

    JX_StartEngine();


    //create a new engine instance and attach it to a new thread
    thread t1 (create_new_engine);
    t1.join();




    Sleep(10 * 1000);

}




void create_new_engine() {

    string homeFolder = "";
    JX_InitializeNewEngine();

    JX_DefineMainFile("console.log('sub engine')");

    JX_StartEngine();

    JXValue obj1;

      // sub engine created at new  thread ,and JX_CreateEmptyObject called fail!

         //Exception thrown: read access violation.
         //__imp_TlsGetValue(...) returned nullptr.

        //program break at :
       //JXCORE_EXTERN(bool)
        //JX_CreateEmptyObject(JXValue *value) {
        // node::commons *com = node::commons::getInstance();

    JX_CreateEmptyObject(&obj1);
    JXValue global;
    JX_GetGlobalObject(&global);
    JX_SetNamedProperty(&global, "NativeBridge", &obj1);


    JX_Free(&obj1);
    JX_Free(&global);

    JX_Loop();

    JX_StopEngine();



}
```

My working enviroment is : windows 10 ,visual studio 2015,runing  in vm fusion on mac

Thanks.